# How to fix "Error Accessing String" error with libusb on windows?

Tags: python, windows, usb

On Windows 10 I am using python 3.10.11 and libusb-package 1.0.26.2 to list all USB devices connected to the computer.

```
import libusb_package

for dev in libusb_package.find(find_all=True):
    print(dev)
```

But for many devices I get an output like this

```
DEVICE ID 0403:6001 on Bus 002 Address 029 =================
 bLength                :   0x12 (18 bytes)
 bDescriptorType        :    0x1 Device
 bcdUSB                 :  0x200 USB 2.0
 bDeviceClass           :    0x0 Specified at interface
 bDeviceSubClass        :    0x0
 bDeviceProtocol        :    0x0
 bMaxPacketSize0        :    0x8 (8 bytes)
 idVendor               : 0x0403
 idProduct              : 0x6001
 bcdDevice              :  0x600 Device 6.0
 iManufacturer          :    0x1 Error Accessing String
 iProduct               :    0x2 Error Accessing String
 iSerialNumber          :    0x3 Error Accessing String
```

where it says "**Error Accessing String**". Is there a way to solve this problem so I can get more information?

P.S. Running the code in an admin terminal does not fix this problem...